# Fonts Not Rendering Correctly

Tags: css, fonts

The font for my title isn't showing up correctly. I used the code below, but for some reason the title is displaying as the default sans-serif, not the font I chose on Google fonts.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using arctext to curve it around an image, could it be related to that?

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);

#site_title{
     color: #ffffff;
     padding-top: 50px;
     text-align: center;
     display: block;
     margin: 0 auto;
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     font-weight: 700;
     letter-spacing: 5px;
     font-size: 40px;
}
```

Comment: did you include the font? show us more code

Comment: well, you have an error in width: declaration, but it shouldn't be an issue. Also, Arctext works fine with web fonts, so it would be useful to know if you're actually loading the font, your snippet of code tells nothing other than that error (and I don't think that is the issue)

Comment: is that font installed on your device?

Comment: Make sure you the font imported in the first line of your css file.  Like:  `@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=montserrat');`

Comment: Yes, I did import the font on the first line.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/7brogf3e/1/  Which raises the question : is your css selector valid? If you change the color, does it get updated?

Comment: @T_D - the whole point is that the fonts are hosted by google so you don't need to worry if the client has the font.

Comment: The selector is valid, all of the styles are working except for the font.